# How To Read XML Response And Show It in a Web Page Using Ajax And Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a web site where I have used a web service called **holidaywebservice**. I have used Jquery and Ajax to request and get response from the server. I have also `console.log(result)` to the console tab of the web browser. Now I want when I request , the response is displayed in the web page (in a table for example)

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-left" id="tblData">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="info">
                        <td>Country</td>
                        <td>HolidayCode</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tbody id="tblBody"></tbody>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
                        '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">' +
                          '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                            '<ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                              '<ns1:countryCode>UnitedStates</ns1:countryCode>' +
                              '<ns1:year>2018</ns1:year>' +
                              '<ns1:month>06</ns1:month>' +
                            '</ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                          '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                        '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

                        //console.log(departureDate);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType:"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            data: str,
                            //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);
                            }

                        });

                });

            </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Response xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetHolidaysForMonthResponse
            xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
            <GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
                <Holiday>
                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                    <HolidayCode>FLAG-DAY</HolidayCode>
                    <Descriptor>Flag Day</Descriptor>
                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                    <Date>2018-06-14T00:00:00</Date>
                </Holiday>
                <Holiday>
                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                    <HolidayCode>FATHERS-DAY</HolidayCode>
                    <Descriptor>Father's Day</Descriptor>
                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                    <Date>2018-06-17T00:00:00</Date>
                </Holiday>
            </GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
        </GetHolidaysForMonthResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Updated.

```
$.ajax({
                            url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                            method: 'POST',
                            contentType:"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                            data: str,
                            //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data);

                                // Parse XML string into an XML document
                                var parsedXml = $.parseXML(data);

                                // Create a jQuery object from the document
                                var myXml = $(parsedXml);

                                // Find each of the Holiday elements
                                var holidays = myXml.find("Holiday");

                                // Iterate through each element
                                holidays.each(function(index, el) {

                                    // This will output <Country>, <HolidayCode>, etc.
                                    var holidayInfo = el.children;
                                    console.log(holidayInfo);

                                })

                            }

                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a native JavaScript solution you could consider the following

```
let soap = response
parser = new DOMParser()
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(soap,"text/xml")


let holidayCount = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Holiday").length
let body = document.getElementById("body")    

for (var i = 0; i < holidayCount; i++) {

    //build table here instead of below elements.        

    let span = document.createElement("span")
    let spanNode = document.createTextNode("Holiday " + i)
    span.appendChild(spanNode)
    body.appendChild(span)

    let country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Country")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    let para = document.createElement("p")
    let node = document.createTextNode("Country: " + country)
    para.appendChild(node)  
    body.appendChild(para)


    let holidayCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HolidayCode")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue)
    let countryPara = document.createElement("p")
    let countryNode = document.createTextNode("HolidayCode: " + holidayCode)
    countryPara.appendChild(CountryNode)    
    body.appendChild(CountryPara)


    }
```

**Here is with building up a table:**

```
let createTd = function(value){
    let td = document.createElement('TD')
    let textNode = document.createTextNode(value)
    td.appendChild(textNode)
    return td  
 }    

let body = document.getElementById("body")
let table = document.createElement('TABLE')
let tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

table.border = '1'
table.appendChild(tableBody);

let heading = ["Country", "HolidayCode", "Descriptor", "HolidayType", "DateType", "BankHoliday", "Date"]   

//TABLE COLUMNS
let tr = document.createElement('TR')
tableBody.appendChild(tr)
for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
    let th = document.createElement('TH')
    th.width = '75'
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]))
    tr.appendChild(th)
}

let parser = new DOMParser()
//soap == the response from your ajax call
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(soap,"text/xml")        

//TABLE ROWS
for (i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Holiday').length; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('TR')      

     let country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Country')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let countryTd = createTd(country)  
     tr.appendChild(countryTd)

     let holidayCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayCode')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let holidayCodeTd = createTd(holidayCode)  
     tr.appendChild(holidayCodeTd)

     let descriptor = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Descriptor')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let descriptorTd = createTd(country)   
     tr.appendChild(descriptorTd)

     let holidayType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let holidayTypeTd = createTd(holidayType)  
     tr.appendChild(holidayTypeTd)

     let dateType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('DateType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let dateTypeTd = createTd(country) 
     tr.appendChild(dateTypeTd)

     let bankHoliday = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('BankHoliday') [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let bankHolidayTd = createTd(bankHoliday)  
     tr.appendChild(bankHolidayTd)

     let date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Date')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
     let dateTd = createTd(date)    
     tr.appendChild(dateTd)         

    tableBody.appendChild(tr)
}  

body.appendChild(table)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ua5eybt0/70/

Here is as close to working example i can come:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="body">


</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    var str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
            '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">' +
              '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
                '<ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
                  '<ns1:countryCode>UnitedStates</ns1:countryCode>' +
                  '<ns1:year>2018</ns1:year>' +
                  '<ns1:month>06</ns1:month>' +
                '</ns1:GetHolidaysForMonth>' +
              '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

            //console.log(departureDate);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType:"text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                data: str,
                //headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat},

                success: function (data) {
                    createTableAndContent(data)
                },                
                error: function (data){
                    console.log(data)
                }


            })


            //Test function
            //createTableAndContent(soap)
    })





     var createTableAndContent = function(data){
        let body = document.getElementById("body")
        let table = document.createElement('TABLE')
        let tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

        table.border = '1'
        table.appendChild(tableBody);

        let heading = ["Country", "HolidayCode", "Descriptor", "HolidayType", "DateType", "BankHoliday", "Date"]   

        //TABLE COLUMNS
        let tr = document.createElement('TR')
        tableBody.appendChild(tr)
        for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
            let th = document.createElement('TH')
            th.width = '75'
            th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]))
            tr.appendChild(th)
        }


        let xmlDoc = data       

        let createTd = function(value){
            let td = document.createElement('TD')
            let textNode = document.createTextNode(value)
            td.appendChild(textNode)
            return td  
        }    


        //TABLE ROWS
        for (i = 0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Holiday').length; i++) {
            let tr = document.createElement('TR')      

            let country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Country')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let countryTd = createTd(country)  
            tr.appendChild(countryTd)

            let holidayCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayCode')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let holidayCodeTd = createTd(holidayCode)  
            tr.appendChild(holidayCodeTd)

            let descriptor = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Descriptor')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let descriptorTd = createTd(country)   
            tr.appendChild(descriptorTd)

            let holidayType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('HolidayType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let holidayTypeTd = createTd(holidayType)  
            tr.appendChild(holidayTypeTd)

            let dateType = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('DateType')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let dateTypeTd = createTd(country) 
            tr.appendChild(dateTypeTd)

            let bankHoliday = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('BankHoliday') [i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let bankHolidayTd = createTd(bankHoliday)  
            tr.appendChild(bankHolidayTd)

            let date = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Date')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            let dateTd = createTd(date)    
            tr.appendChild(dateTd)         

            tableBody.appendChild(tr)
        }  

        body.appendChild(table)
    }




    //Data for testing.
    let soap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetHolidaysForMonthResponse
            xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/">
            <GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
                <Holiday>
                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                    <HolidayCode>FLAG-DAY</HolidayCode>
                    <Descriptor>Flag Day</Descriptor>
                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                    <Date>2018-06-14T00:00:00</Date>
                </Holiday>
                <Holiday>
                    <Country>UnitedStates</Country>
                    <HolidayCode>FATHERS-DAY</HolidayCode>
                    <Descriptor>Father's Day</Descriptor>
                    <HolidayType>Notable</HolidayType>
                    <DateType>ObservedActual</DateType>
                    <BankHoliday>NotRecognized</BankHoliday>
                    <Date>2018-06-17T00:00:00</Date>
                </Holiday>
            </GetHolidaysForMonthResult>
        </GetHolidaysForMonthResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`


</script>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smaf0qv2/6/

Comment: Why only one semi-colon? You're also missing a closing quote near the end.

Comment: @Mattias - Console shows this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in this line " let country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Country"[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue ". How can I fix it ??

Comment: And I added the missing ). After that I got this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in this line " let holidayCode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HolidayCode)[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue ". How can I Fix this ??

Comment: I have used 2nd sample codes. But , it gives me this error - Holi.php:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: soap is not defined. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: @Amithash read his code comments more carefully - it says `//soap == the response from your ajax call`

Comment: @user7290573 - That's what I want to know. How can I add response to this ?? without pasting the results..

Comment: @Amithash - You add the code inside the success function of your ajax call.The data that is passed into the success function equals the response/soap in my code.

Comment: @MattiasJosephson - I didn't understand. Can you please implement one and only answer ?? Because I'm very new to js.

Comment: @Amithash - Try working with the third example. Good luck :)

Comment: @MattiasJosephson - But , sitll I have a question. How can I get response without hard coded ??

Comment: @Amithash I am not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MattiasJosephson - If I want to display responses, I have to write the responses in the "let soap". It's not possible to hard code responses. Then How can I display responses without coded into the "let soap" ??

Comment: @Amithash - Try remove the parsing of the data. Remove the line  "let parser = new DOMParser()"  and *change* the next line to "let xmlDoc = data"

Comment: @MattiasJosephson - Now it's shows me this error - Uncaught TypeError: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName is not a function. I tried to solve. But, I was unable to fix this. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: @Amitrash - Did you get any error before you removed the parsing code?

Comment: @MattiasJosephson - No.. What Can I do now ??

Comment: @Amithash I have updated the code sample. I removed the xml parsing. This example works for me in both IE, Firefox and Chrome. I just had to add CORS allow extensions to Firefox and Chrome to able to run the sample locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `parseXML` function to convert the response into an object which you can then pull the data from:

```
// Parse XML string into an XML document
var parsedXml = $.parseXML(data);

// Create a jQuery object from the document
var myXml = $(parsedXml);

// Find each of the Holiday elements
var holidays = myXml.find("Holiday");

// Iterate through each element
holidays.each(function(index, el) {

    // This will output <Country>, <HolidayCode>, etc.
    var holidayInfo = el.children;
    console.log(holidayInfo);

})
```

Comment: Where do I need to put these things ?? Under success: function (data) { ?? I have updated the answer with my new ajax codes. Is it correct or not ??

Comment: What does it say in your console when you try your code now?

Comment: Nothing , thats the case.. :/

Comment: How can I Fix this ??

Comment: So `console.log(data)` shows nothing? What about before?

Comment: console.log(data) gives me the xml response. I meant I didn't get anything after adding above codes.

Comment: Ok, in that case you should check to see if it's being parsed: add `console.log($.parseXML(data))` or `console.log(parsedXml)`.